# how to get books information from amazon web service

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm totally new to Amazon Web Service. I need to get book info from Amazon for my web app. I checked out Amazon Web Service but there are so many products and services. Which one should I focus on?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you want the [advertising API](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html) -- it's not limited to just books, as it supports other products sold by Amazon too, but it does seem to be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Usually Amazon supply documentation to all of its products (EC2,S3,..)
On http://aws.amazon.com/

After you select your code language, you will find more specific documentation to what you need.

e.g.
I use python's boto which has additional documentation to aws's.
http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/